# Delphi 11, tDictionary containing tObjects

Tags: delphi, tdictionary

I have a tDictionary of variant items, I can add anything I wish, including objects.

My app has a "render" function that iterates through the dictionary and converts whatever it finds into string and finally displays them all as a single document.

I also have a number of classes that ALL have a "render" function that returns a string.  I can add the class objects to my main dictionary if I explicitly render them: myDict['foo'] := mySubClass.render();

What I want is to add the class object: myDict['foo'] := mySubClass;

When the main render operation discovers an object, it should call the "render" function of that object.  Similarly, if said object also contains objects, they should be rendered in turn.  Like a coiled spring unwinding.

In PHP I simply used "if(is_object($itemArr[idx]) then $itemArr[idx]->render()"

I can't do this in Delphi, because the IDE does not know what the object is at design time.

How can I resolve this?

edited to show that I don't want to itemise the classes.

Comment: Use the [`is` operator](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Class_References#The_is_Operator) as in `if Variable is Type then`, where the variable is the object and the type is the class. This is as basic as your PHP approach, tho.

Comment: Does that mean I would have to ask if v = class1, if v= class2, if v=class3 ......

Comment: If all those classes have no common ancestor: yes. That's where [inheritance in OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) makes things easier.

Comment: OK - if I can make that work, you get the point :)

Comment: This also includes polymorphism!

Comment: Sounds like interfaces would be the right approach here. Your dict should have values that implement an interface that defines the functionality you need.